# How do expose my own meta data in WCF service?

Tags: wcf

Rather than exposing the system generated meta data I'd like to provide my meta data which is kept it a text file (say) on the server. I guess this means responding to the HTTP GET request http://[service address]?wdsl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply turn off metadata export (remove serviceMetadataBehavior or set its httpGetEnabled flag to false) and then put your WSDL document at a URL that makes sense for your app (?wsdl is a WCF / ASMX convention but its not a standard)

This is pretty easy if you are using IIS hosting but would need a REST endpoint for Self Hosting

Comment: I want to use self hosting - can you please point me in the right direction to find out about adding a REST endpoint?

Comment: This is a reasonable guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx. You will need an operation that returns a stream and return a FileStream that is open on your WSDL file

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a custom MetaExporter and then find ServiceMetadataBehavior, in that behavior, you can override the default MetadataExporter.
Therefore in your MetaExporter, you can do anything you want.